# How to backport a 6.1.1 jsf portlet to get it running on a 6.1.0 liferay portal?

Tags: java, exception, liferay, portlet, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to get an 6.1.1 Portlet running on a 6.1.0 Liferay CE Portal. The JSF Portlet uses the ServiceBuilder and a lot of other Util API classes of Liferay.

I thought the best idea would be to recompile the portlet with the correct liferay-plugins-sdk.
After downloading the 6.1.0 SDK, replacing it in the eclipse project, and rebuild it, I get
a couple of exceptions. They occur immediately after starting the server.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Bean class [com.liferay.portal.kernel.spring.util.SpringFactoryUtil] not found
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/cluster-spring.xml]
Bean ''; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.spring.util.SpringFactoryUtil
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:491)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.processBeanDefinition(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortletApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(PortletApplicationContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortletContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortletContextLoaderListener.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderServletContextListener.doPortalInit(PortalClassLoaderServletContextListener.java:91)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:61)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:53)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:52)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PortalClassLoaderServletContextListener.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1362)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1450)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1485)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.spring.util.SpringFactoryUtil
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.util.FilterClassLoader.loadClass(FilterClassLoader.java:41)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.createBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.java:63)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.createBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:472)
    ... 41 more
```

Has someone a good idea? I also posted this issue on the official forum , but maybe here I reach more people...

Here is the link to the forum: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/19124222

**==== Update 1====**

To solve the above exception I ran the service-builder within the 6.1.0 portlet again.

Now it is possible to start the server with the portlet, buuut
the portlet is not visible/available in the portal for adding in a page and I get the
following **ClassNotFoundException: PortletBeanLocatorUtil**:

```
12:24:06,627 ERROR [PortletContextLoaderListener:132] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.util.bean.PortletBeanLocatorUtil
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.util.bean.PortletBeanLocatorUtil
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortletContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortletContextLoaderListener.java:118)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderServletContextListener.doPortalInit(PortalClassLoaderServletContextListener.java:91)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.flushInits(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:45)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.initPlugins(MainServlet.java:813)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1581)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you give a link to the liferay.com forum in order to crossreference (and crossreference there as well, so that everybody can learn from the solution?

Comment: Sorry, I had to change the whole thing because I realized that I tested my now-6.1.0-sdk-portlet on my 6.1.1 portal. After I downloaded a 6.1.0 liferay and deploy the now-6.1.0-sdk-portlet I get the described errors... in the post in the forum I have the old error messages left. So this here is the current state

Comment: Did you run service-builder after changing the SDK to the other version?

Comment: Question: Do I have to start the servicebuilder again after switching to 6.1.0 sdk?

Comment: Oh, didn't see your new comment(you're a fast one ;)). OK, this is not good: When I clicked on "build services" again, I get this little piece of error message in a dialog: "An internal error occurred during: "Build services".
java.lang.NullPointerException". Also restarted eclipse and tried again, but that didn't help. Looks like I have to create a new Post on stackoverflow... :(

Comment: Based on this, it looks like you've been running the 6.1.1 generated code with the 6.1.0 runtime classes for servicebuilder components. This means that you'll have to identify where it changed (after all, you're backporting to an earlier version, even though it's only a minor version). You might succeed faster with deleting the old servicebuilder generated code and generate new from scratch - I can't tell you off the top of my head which files are read (though you might find this out when you look at the NullpointerException stacktrace, it might give a hint)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Where can I see the stacktrace? I only get a dialog with that little description(already clicked on "<< details"-button) console is empty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22574/discussion-between-olaf-kock-and-abeing)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to recompile the portlet in the 6.1.0 sdk. Especially when you use ServiceBuilder: you're running with a code generator that is probably relying on the runtime files that come matching runtime to generated code.

For pure JSR-286 portlets, they are easily compatible even across major versions. If you use more sophisticated code, e.g. ServiceBuilder or the API, lots of effort is taken to keep it compatible, but no guarantee can be given that it actually is binary compatible - sorry, that's life.

For Liferay's own plugins, you're asked to use matching versions - they're not tested between updates. And they most likely use ServiceBuilder and the API as well.